# Exception while trying to call rest endpoint with DTO request and separate MultipartFile-Array

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, jackson, spring-webflux

I'm trying to send a post request with two body parts:

1. RequestDTO
2. MultipartFile[] - array

I've tried to send it as a List and disabled `FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` though there is a content in MultipartFile array

I haven't found any information about sending multipart/form-data request with complex data (JSON-String and separate array of files). Even if I try to send only one file, I'm getting the same exception.

What could be the source of this error? Am I missing something?

My java code:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Service
public class RestService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> startProcess(MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> data) {
        if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
            log.info("Client call \"/endpoint\" with request: {}", data.get("request"));
        }

        final var response = this.webClient.post()
                                           .uri(RestEndpoints.ENDPOINT)
                                           .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(data))
                                           .retrieve()
                                           .toEntity(ResponseDTO.class)
                                           .block();
        if (response != null && response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return response;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("There is an error");
    }

    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> sendToClient(RequestDTO rq, MultipartFile[] files) {
        final var multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("request", rq);
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("files", files);
        final var payload = multipartBodyBuilder.build();
        return this.startProcess(payload);
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:256) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:158) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.doOnRequest(MonoSingle.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.request(Operators.java:2878) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoSingle.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFromMonoOperator.subscribe(FluxFromMonoOperator.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78) ~


....



reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:887) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:286) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:887) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable$MonoCallableSubscription.request(MonoCallable.java:159) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.request(FluxConcatArray.java:276) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany$SendManyInner.onSubscribe(MonoSendMany.java:254) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8773) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray$ConcatArraySubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatArray.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatArray.subscribe(FluxConcatArray.java:78) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8773) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.netty.channel.MonoSendMany.subscribe(MonoSendMany.java:102) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.netty.FutureMono.doSubscribe(FutureMono.java:122) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.netty.FutureMono$DeferredFutureMono.subscribe(FutureMono.java:114) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:147) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4495) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.5.7.jar:3.5.7]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:445) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:195) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:456) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelActive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:62) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.8.jar:1.1.8]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelActive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:69) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelActive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:211) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:260) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:238) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at ....


io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList[0]->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1308) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:30) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:399) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1568) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:252) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 101 more
```

**UPDATE**

Here is how API looks like

```json
"/endpoint": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "controller"
        ],
        "operationId": "start",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "multipart/form-data": {
              "schema": {
                "required": [
                  "request",
                  "files"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "bestandswechsel": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestDTO"
                  },
                  "files": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "format": "binary"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "required": [
                  "request",
                  "files"
                ],
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "request": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/RequestDTO"
                  },
                  "files": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "format": "binary"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          ......
        }
      }
    },
```

and this is the controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> start(@Valid
                         @RequestPart("request")
                         RequestDto request,
                         @RequestPart("files")
                         MultipartFile[] files)
```

After trying to convert files into an array of strings I was able to send the request. But the controller failes with following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'files' is not present]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `MultipartBodyBuilder.part` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/MultipartBodyBuilder.html#part(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)):

> Add a part where the Object may be:
> String -- form field
> Resource -- file part
> Object -- content to be encoded (e.g. to JSON)
> HttpEntity -- part content and headers although generally it's easier to add headers through the returned builder
> Part -- a part from a server request

So with `multipartBodyBuilder.part("files", files);` since `files` is a `MultipartFile[]` it is considered as an option 3 - Object to be encoded. To attach files use `MultipartFile.getResource()`, e.g.:

```
    MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        bodyBuilder.part(file.getName(), file.getResource());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in a comment, response should be in a form `{   "request": { ... }, "files": [ "string" ] }`. That means your response is not a multipart, but a typical json. Thus, you have to read files content to array of strings, compose a typical response object and pass it as a prebuild object. Here as an example, i've used a `Map<>` as a response, however you could define a custom class with `request` and `files` fields

```
    String[] filesContent = new String[files.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        MultipartFile file = files[i];
        byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();
        Charset charset = Optional.ofNullable(MediaType.parseMediaType(file.getContentType()).getCharset())
                .orElse(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // or pick Charset somehow
        // assume file is a text, otherwise convert it to string as you wish
        String stringContent = new String(fileBytes, charset);
        filesContent[i] = stringContent;
    }

    Map<String, Object> response = Map.of("request", rq, "files", filesContent);
    webClient.post()
            //
            .bodyValue(response)
            ///
```

Comment: API requires an array of files ```{
  "request": {
    ...
  },
  "files": [
    "string"
  ]
}```. I can't send multiple body parts with separate filenames.

Comment: Is each "string" a content of text file?

Comment: Yes. that's how API looks like. It could also be a PDF. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the API.

Comment: That means it requires a json, not an multipart. I've updated the answer

Comment: Well I can now call Rest API, but I'm getting an error on provider's side now...

Comment: I've updated my question with new error and added full api doc